# Usuarios en Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, login, autenticación

Necesito adaptar el sistema de autenticación de Laravel, de modo que el usuario tenga un campo adicional, llamado `login`. Eso lo hago en la migration sin problemas.
El problema viene cuando se usa todo el sistema de registro y autenticación de usuario. Primero tengo que hacer que el formulario de registro pida el nuevo campo, junto con los demás, así como pasarlo a la validación. Todo esto esto está en los traits de Laravel de una forma bastante críptica, que no veo como sobrescribirlos adecuadamente.
Luego, al acceder el usuario debería poder teclear, indistintamente, su login o su email como identificador, de modo que si la aplicación detecta que es un email, valide contra el email, y si detecta que no es un email, valide contra el login. Esto es muy habitual en muchas aplicaciones, para que el usuario pueda acceder con cualquiera de ambos datos, indistintamente, pero en Laravel no sé como plantearlo.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de laravel utiliizas?

Comment: La última, la 5.8.

Comment: Revisa estos 2 links: https://tutsforweb.com/laravel-auth-login-email-username-one-field/ y https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-login-email-username-one-field/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu controlador `LoginController` le indicarás que use `email` o `username.

```
public function findUsername()
    {
        $login = request()->input('login');

        $fieldType = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

        request()->merge([$fieldType => $login]);

        return $fieldType;
    }
```